# How to say 'I miss you' in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, classical-latin, word-request

How can I say "I miss you" in the sense that one misses someone and desires to be again with this someone nonetheless it is alive or death?

My dicctionary only list: *miror*, which is more like being surprised or amazed.

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to say this; what to say exactly depends on context and to a certain extent your mood... They all tend to revolve around the word *desiderare* or *desiderium*.

The simplest way would be to say: **te desidero**.

*Desiderare* is said of the living, not least lovers (e.g. *me ames, me desideres*), and the dead (e.g. after a battle), and of inanimate things (e.g. *gloriam*). It is only said of people or things that aren't present, but it has a strong sense of longing or (surprise!) desire.

Still it may feel a little anodyne depending on the circumstances, and if that should be the case, you can go further and say, for example, *(summo) desiderio tui flagro* (or *teneor*). That's going pretty far, of course.

*Cupere* is another possibility. *Cupio the videre* for example -- but that's not something you write to your tax consultant to make an appointment.

Answer (score 5):

There's not one word that expresses this as definitively as English's modern usage, so you have a variety of options, including those that Sebastian listed, and especially if you add something like *reditus* to it.

I'll also add ***careo*** to the mix. It's more typical meaning is "to lack something [that you want to have]," which covers the absence part of "to miss." From L&S:

> With the access. idea of the subjective state of mind or feeling, **to feel the want of a thing,** ***to miss***: triste enim est nomen ipsum carendi, quia subicitur haec vis; habuit, non habet; “desiderat, requirit, indiget,” Cic. Tusc. 1, 36, 87; cf. “the context: carere igitur hoc significat, egere eo quod habere velis,” id. ib. § “88: non caret is qui non desiderat,” id. Sen. 14, 47.

I especially like Cicero's simple definiton of *carere*: **habuit, non habet; desiderat, requirit, indiget**.

In fact, Cicero has a mixture of *carere* and *desiderare* in the same passage:

> non mehercule aequo animo te careo; te autem quid mirum, qui Dionysium tanto opere desiderem?

Comment: extrañar?, extraneo?